# How to drop columns that end with a specific wildcard string?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a series of columns:

```
 COLUMNS = contract_number, award_date_x,   publication_date_x, award_date_y,   publication_date_y, award_date, publication_date
```

I would like to drop all of the 'publication_date' columns that end with '_[a+z'], so that my final result would look like this:

```
 COLUMNS = contract_number, award_date, award_date_x, award_date_y, publication_date
```

I have tried the following with no luck:

```
df_merge=df_merge.drop(c for c in df_merge.columns if c.str.contains('publication_date_[a+z]$'))
```

Thanks

Comment: `c` at this point is a string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```py
import re

columns = df_merge.columns.tolist() # getting all columns

for col in columns:
    if re.match(r"publication_date_[a-z]$",col): #regex for your match case
        df_merge.drop([col], axis=1, inplace=True) # If regex matches, then remove the column

df_merge.head() # Filtered dataframe
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lis = ["publication_date_x", "publication_date", "publication_date_x_y_y", "hello"]

new_list = [x for x in lis if not x.startswith('publication_date_')]
```

the output will be

```
new_list: ["publication_date", "hello"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `str.contains` you'll need to make the list of columns a Series.

```
series_cols = pd.Series(df_merge.columns)
bool_series_cols = series_cols.str.contains('publication_date_[a-z]$')

df_merge.drop([c for c, bool_c in zip(series_cols, bool_series_cols) if bool_c], axis=1, inplace=True)
```